# Select tag not firing the event handler

Tags: javascript, html, css

For a project, I am using vanilla HTML/CSS/JS. I am trying to hide all items in a page, have a default option to be selected in the select tag, only show the element that has the selected id and use the dropdown menu to select periods of time and only show that particular element.

In my files, I have structured the function in this way. I have a console log to make sure to see if the code gets ran or not. It puts the log out only once and does not trigger no matter what I choose in the filter. I think the problem is with my event handler not firing but I am sure I followed the examples. What could be the problem here?

```js
var day = document.getElementById("day");
var week = document.getElementById("week");
var month = document.getElementById("month");

period = document.getElementById("filter");
function loadPost(period) {
    // Hide all posts
    day.style.display = "none";
    week.style.display = "none";
    month.style.display = "none";
    switch (period) {
        case day:
            showDay();
            break;
        case week:
            showWeek();
            break;
        case month:
            showMonth();
            break;
    } 
    console.log(period);
}
function showDay() {
    day.style.display = "block";
}
function showWeek() {
    week.style.display = "block";
}
function showMonth() {
    month.style.display = "block";
}
period.addEventListener("change", loadPost(period.value));
```

```html
        <div class="most-popular">
            <h1>Most Popular</h1>
            <label for="most-popular-filter">Filter:</label>
            <select name="most-popular-filter" id="filter">
                <option value="day">Day</option>
                <option value="week">Week</option>
                <option value="month">Month</option>
            </select>
            <div class="content-box" id="day">
                <img src="images/placeholder.png" alt="most-popular">
                <h2>Most Popular 1</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam, quae.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content-box" id="week">
                <img src="images/placeholder.png" alt="most-popular">
                <h2>Most Popular 2</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam, quae.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content-box" id="month">
                <img src="images/placeholder.png" alt="most-popular">
                <h2>Most Popular 3</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam, quae.</p>
            </div>      
        </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use callback function and inside invoke other function:

```js
period.addEventListener("change", ()=>loadPost(period.value));
```

Comment: Why is that the case? What would be the use of the arrow operator and why is my implementation faulty?

Comment: period.addEventListener("change", function(){loadPost(period.value)}); It will work also , but in case of arrow function "this" instance of outer function will not work for the arrow function if there is an outer function (type of case).